# Set one to one and one to many both relationships among two tables

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, ef-code-first-mapping

I have two tables called employee and team. I want to set relationships among the tables as follows.

1. employee belongs to a team.  (1: m relationship).
2. team has a team leader (team leader is also an employee). (1:1 relationship)

   employee table

   [primary key]  
   public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }  
   public string Name { get; set; }  
   public string Email { get; set; }

   team table

   [primary key]  
   public string Name { get; set; }  
   public string Description { get; set; }  
   How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

team.cs:

```
 public class team
        {
            private TeamLeaderDbContext Context { get; set; }
            [Key]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int? leaderID { get; set; }
            public employee leader { get { return Context.employees.Find(leaderID); } }
            public ICollection<employee> employees { get; set; }
        }
```

employee.cs:

```
public class employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

TeamLeaderDbContext:

```
public class TeamLeaderDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TeamLeaderDbContext(DbContextOptions<TeamLeaderDbContext> options)
             : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<team> teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<employee> employees { get; set; }
    }
```

homecontroller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TeamLeaderDbContext _context;

        public HomeController(TeamLeaderDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var team = _context.teams.Include(c => c.employees).ToList();
            return View();
        }
}
```

result:

[image]